# How do I set different themes for GTK+2 and GTK+3?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I rather like the Azure GTK+3 theme, unfortunately it doesn't play nice with GTK+2 applications like Scilab (which I am running from the binary tarball provided at scilab.org, not the Scilab package in Ubuntu 17.10's repositories, as I want Scilab 6.0.1, as opposed to the version 5.5.2 in 17.10's repositories). Here's a screenshot so you can see how hideous its theming looks:

[image]

Is it possible to set the GTK+2 theme to Radiance without also changing the GTK+3 theme to Radiance? That is, I'd like the GTK+2 theme set to Radiance, and the GTK+3 theme set to Azure. Is this possible?

I have tried doing this with LXAppearance (from LXDE, to be clear I am using GNOME, however), as I know when I am running i3 LXAppearance can be used effectively to change GTK+2 theme, unfortunately changing theme in LXAppearance does not seem to make any change at all to the GTK+2 theme used in other applications.